# How to Set a min value on a date field on page init in blazor razor page

Tags: blazor

I Have a date component, on a blazor, razor page where I would like to set the min date when the page is loaded
But I don't know how to bind the min value.
No matter what i do, min date doesnt work. The user can still select an older date in the component
(Binding the value field works fine @bind-value=@DateFromValue)

The problem is I have no idea how to bind min to DateMin

```
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="trip-start" @bind-value=@DateFromValue min=@DateMin />
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="trip-start" @bind-value=@DateFromValue @bind-min=@DateMin />
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="trip-start" @bind-value=@DateFromValue @bind-min="@DateMin" />
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="trip-start" @bind-value=@DateFromValue @bind:min="DateMin" />
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="trip-start" @bind-value=@DateFromValue @bind:min="@DateMin" />


@code {
    private DateTime DateFromValue { get; set; } 
    private DateTime DateMin { get; set; } 
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        DateMin = DateTime.Now;;
        DateFromValue = DateTime.Now;
        DateToValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

I tried different ways of binding the property but couldnt get anything to work
No matter what the min date isnt respected

Comment: Make sure to use the correct format for dates in html5 : `min=@DateMin.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: But be aware browser support is not there - safari noticeably is missing support for this. You should also validate/enforce the rule in your code.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thank you, that worked. And yes I will be validating the input.

Comment: I have moved my comment to an answer - please mark it as accepted, thanks

Comment: If you only want dates then consider using the `DateOnly` type. It makes equality checking much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to use the correct format for dates in html5 e.g. 2023-04-14

`min=@DateMin.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`